# Laravel S3 - File not found at path - when trying to move a file from a different directory in S3

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3

I am trying to move an S3 file to a different directory in S3.

This is my code:

```
Storage::disk('s3')->move("https://my-s3-url.s3.aws.com/old-path/image.png","/new-folder/123/image.png");
```

The problem with this is I am getting this error:

```
League\Flysystem\FileNotFoundException  : File not found at path: https://my-s3-url.s3.aws.com/old-path/image.png
```

But, when I checked that file in the browser, that file really exists.

I am also certain that when I uploaded that file before, I used `s3` as the `Storage::Disk()`.

What seems to be the problem here? TIA!

Answer (score 3):

I just realized my own mistake here.

I solved this by not putting the entire AWS S3 URL of the old URL. So instead of putting this:

`https://my-s3-url.s3.aws.com/old-path/image.png`

It should only be this:
`/old-path/image.png`.

So my code looks like this:

```
Storage::disk('s3')->move("/old-path/image.png","/new-folder/123/image.png");
```

Hope this helps anyone.